Variance of pink noise derived from gaussian white noise of known variance
Say that we've sampled white noise from a 0-centered gaussian distribution with variance $\sigma^2$. We now derive pink noise by $1/f$ filtering. Will the resulting pink noise have a neat and simple formula for its variance?
The reason I'm asking is because I'd like to generate pink noise of some given variance (in turn derived from a signal-to-noise ratio).

This will depend on how exactly you implement the $1/f$ filter. Most practical implementation will use some sort of approximation and also roll off the gain at the lower frequencies (since $1/f$ can get very large down there).
Assuming you implement this as an LTI system with a transfer function you can estimate the gain of the filter by simply calculating the RMS in the frequency domain.
However, by far the simplest method is to calculate the variance directly. Since both the filter signal will be mean free, the variance is simply
$$\sigma_p = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_p^2[n] $$

Thank you. I suppose I could just calculate the population variance and then scale the noise appropriately.
